# Running QT for Embedded linux app -- on desktop i-86 PC

Tags: qt, qemu

I need to build QT gui (it is simple GUI with two button) for embedded linux platform which have ARM11 processor (same as RPI have). Gui will run on target & will have 7 Inch 800x480 touch screen.
Please correct me here in the steps which i will follow :--

1> configure QT library for ARM & LinuxFb support  then build QT library using cross-compiler for ARM11.
   Do i need my target root file system to build QT library in this way `?`

2> Then make your QT creator to configure to use arm11 cross compiler. And cross compile your app against this cross-compiled QT library.

3> Configure & install QT for arm.

4> Now run your app  using QEMU.
   Do i need my target root file system or target  kernel to run the QT cross-compiled  app in QEMU `?`
   Also as my desktop is running using X11 & my GUI will be using DirectFb,  will my application crash `?`

Please correct me in the above steps (if some one have set this environment before) and also  try to answer few questions asked above .

Comment: Please can someone suggest on this.. ?

Comment: Have u tried buildroot?